# Can a player rotate from the back line after the serve and become a blocker?

Tags: rules, volleyball

Can a player rotate from the back line after the serve and become a blocker? Or is the designation of backline player at the time of the serve?

Answer (score 4):

A back-row player (one of the three players in the back row at the time of the serve, including the server) is not allowed to block.  If they do, it is a blocking fault and results in a point for the other team.

From the [FIVB Official Volleyball Rules 2013-2016](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp), Rule 14.6 (Blocking Faults):

> **14.6 Blocking Faults**
>   14.6.2 A back-row player or a Libero completes a block or participates in a 
>   completed block.

Answer (score 2):

No, he can't. It's a fault and the point is given to the other team.

Also, a back-row player can complete an attack in two ways:

1. at any height from behind the front zone if at his/her take-off, the player's feet didn't touch or cros the attack line
2. from the front zone if at the moment of the contact a part of the ball is lower than the top of the net.

[FIVB Rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp)